# Dropbox JavaScript SDK suddenly gives "Dropbox.Dropbox is not a constructor" error

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am using Dropbox `JavaScript` SDK. Until 8 Jun 2020 my upload code worked fine but after 8 Jun 2020 it gives an error. See below for the code and error:

code

```
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '<?php echo DROP_BOX_TOKEN; ?>';
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN});
```

error

> Uncaught TypeError: Dropbox.Dropbox is not a constructor

Thanks

Comment: How do you load dropbox into your script? `<script src="...">` tag? Where is it placed? Does the script element have other attributes like `defer` or `async`?

Comment: Also, please post text as text (including code), not as image.

Comment: @trincot i load script like below and no any other attribute given in script tag

<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropbox/dist/Dropbox-sdk.min.js"></script>

Comment: Remains the question: where is the script element placed? In `head`, at start of `body`, end of `body`? Could you please update your question with text instead of image?

Comment: @trincot I load script in head tag

Comment: Does source code is downloaded automatically via some tools like NPM or is it local file that never changes?

Comment: This is an issue on the Dropbox side. We're working on it. I'll follow up here once I have an update on this.

Comment: Please, add all info to your question, don't leave it just in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now fixed with the latest release and should be working properly again.